# R Add CDF Columns to DataFrame

Tags: r, dataframe, cumulative-frequency

Suppose I have the following R dataframe:

[image]

The Peril and Range columns are both factors. And I want to create a cumulative distribution column for Counts and Value like so:

[image]

How would I do this? I am using dplyr if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the data stored in `df` this should work:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Peril) %>%
  mutate(
    'Count CDF' = cumsum(Counts) / sum(Counts),
    'Values CDF' = cumsum(Values) / sum(Values)
  )
```

However your first and second table seem to have different counts and values for the 'Other' Peril.